# Composer rest server TLS private key and cert clarification

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, tls1.2, hyperledger-composer

I am studying composer rest server functionalities in detail .

I have a clarification on **securing rest server with TLS** . 
I know for a fact that the rest server can be secured or give https functionality by giving **-t true and giving -e certFile and -k keyFile**

These cert and key files are our certificates right and not the crypto-config generated key and certs right . And what type of certificates/key can i use .
An example would be appreciated on how to use self signed certificates .

This might seem stupid but just wanted a clarification . 
Thanks .

Comment: They are a cert/key combo that a CA administrator in an Org chooses to deploy to encrypt communications between the REST server instance and its REST clients. These could be PEM files generated by openssl for example.  The crypto-config stuff is typically via Fabric's cryptogen tool to generate the cryptographic material (x509 certs etc), such as for BYFN sample network.

Comment: so i cant use the crytpogen generated key and vert for composer rest server -e and -k .  What can i use ?

Comment: cryptogen does generate tls certificates for use by fabric so you could use those to test with or you can use openssl as the tool to generate your own self signed tls certificates. There will be plenty examples if you google on it on how to use openssl to do this. In a production world you would obtain certificates from a well known authority to secure the rest server using tls